# Completely disable thread safety in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to completely disable illegal crossthreads checking with

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

I ended up looking for this after i realized that i wasn't able to have multiple tabs in a TabControl with multiple WebBrowser controls and changing the GUI -the WebBrowser control actually- in all tabs at the same time.

The problem is that i need CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to be completely disabled but it seems that i get a cross-thread error even if i put it in my code. Is there anything extra, like a setting or something that i should tweak?

Comment: show us your code please. . .

Comment: @Werdna i can't edit my question for some reason. May i post it to pastebin and answer with the link here?

Comment: I can edit your question just fine.What happens when you click edit?

Comment: Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is like like having a minefield surrounded by guards to prevent someone accidentally getting blown up and you dismiss the guards. You can now go for a stroll through the minefield, but it hasn't made the minefield safe. One wrong step and you are going to get blown up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is really not a good idea. Why don't you just make your code thread-safe instead?

It's actually easier than a lot think. What you have to do is call a method which checks the `InvokeRequired` property of the form. If it returns `True`, the function will invoke itself and then execute the specified task.

Here's how you'd do it in **.NET 4.0 or higher**:

```
Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Method As Action)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then '"Me" being the current form.
        Me.Invoke(Sub() InvokeIfRequired(Method)) 'Invoke this method to make it thread-safe.
    Else
        Method.Invoke() 'Execute the specified method.
    End If
End Sub
```

And here's how you'd do it in **.NET 3.5 or lower**:

```
Delegate Sub InvocationDelegate(ByVal Method As Action)

Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Method As Action)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then '"Me" being the current form.
        Me.Invoke(New InvocationDelegate(AddressOf InvokeIfRequired), Method) 'Invoke this method to make it thread-safe.
    Else
        Method.Invoke() 'Execute the specified method.
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Example usage:**

.NET 4.0 or higher:

```
'Thread-safely sets Label1's text.
InvokeIfRequired(Sub() Label1.Text = "Hello World!")
```

.NET 3.5 or lower:

```
'Thread-safely sets Label1's text.
InvokeIfRequired(AddressOf SetNewText)

...further down in code...

Private Sub SetNewText()
    Label1.Text = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```