# Randomize User agent GeckoFX

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, gecko, geckofx

is there a way of randomizing the user agent using Gecko Browser ? i tried doing it on a separated thread but i couldn't since Gecko must be ran on the same Thread.

Comment: _Show us what you've tried_. Also, [_**invocation**_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37016125/3740093)

Comment: all what i'v done was adding a background worker with a loop + thread.sleep() for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Create new class Global.cs

> public class Globals
>       {
>           public static ArrayList Useragent = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
> }
> ```

next in your form1 code

> private string GetUserAgent()
>           {
>
> ```
>         Random Rnd = new Random();
>         return Convert.ToString(Globals.Useragent[Rnd.Next(0, Globals.Useragent.Count)]);
>     }
> ```

load your file with user agent lines

> private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               var OpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();
>               OpenFile.Filter = "*.txt | *.txt";
>               OpenFile.ShowDialog();
>               if (OpenFile.FileName != "")
>               {
>                   Globals.Useragent.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(OpenFile.FileName));
>
> ```
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("Chooee Your User agent file");
>         }
>     }
> ```

======================

> private string GetUserAgent()
>           {
>
> ```
>         Random Rnd = new Random();
>         return Convert.ToString(Globals.Useragent[Rnd.Next(0, Globals.Useragent.Count)]);
>     }
> ```

Ok its finish!

Now you can do this - input your new code GetUserAgent();

> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>              CookieManager.RemoveAll();
>               Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = GetUserAgent();
>                   }